# Scipy.optimize.minimize using a design vector x that contains integers only

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, integer, minimum

I'd like to minimize some objective function f(x1,x2,x3) in Python. Its quite a simple function but the problem is that the design vector x=[x1,x2,x3] constains integers only.

So for example I'd like to get the result:

"f is minimum for x=[1, 3, 2]" and not: 
"f is minimum for x=[1.12, 3.36, 2.24]" since this would not make any sense for my problem.

Is there any way to rig scipy.minimize to solve this kind of problem? Or is there any other Python library capable of doing this?

Comment: Optimising a non-continuous function is very hard, and `scipy` is not capable of doing it.

Comment: what is the domain of x1, x2, x3. What are your speed constraints? Will it always be a function of 3 variables? These are important considerations imo

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a way harder problem speaking math, the same algorithm will not be capable! This problem is np-hard. Maybe check out pyglpk... And check out mixed integer programming.

Comment: I think this is ambiguous, if the function is always of a constant number variables then a brute force approach is indeed polynomial time in the domains ofthe variables (Though it could be high order).

Comment: I considered the brute force approach but the design vector actually contains 15 variables that can all become 20 different values. So 20^15 combinations will take far too long, even if the objective function is very simple. I'll check out pyglpk and integer programming now, as Schorsch suggested.